# Hive Load Data:No files matching path file:/home/hive/sample.log

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to load `sample.log` file on HDP-sandbox
My initial efforts

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'sample.log' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE logs;
```

It seems that path is not matching

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:23 Invalid path ''sample.log'': No files matching path file:/home/hive/sample.log (state=42000,code=40000)
```

I logged out,moved to /root,then entered `hive`

```
0: jdbc:hive2://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:2> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/root/Hadoop_Spark_Fundamentals_Code_Notes-V3.0/Lesson-6/Lesson-6.2_Hive/sample.log' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE logs;
```

Full path does not work either.

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:23 Invalid path ''/root/Hadoop_Spark_Fundamentals_Code_Notes-V3.0/Lesson-6/Lesson-6.2_Hive/sample.log'': No files matching path file:/root/Hadoop_Spark_Fundamentals_Code_Notes-V3.0/Lesson-6/Lesson-6.2_Hive/sample.log (state=42000,code=40000)
```

It looks to me that it confuses /root and /home/hive.

How to set the proper path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is being executed by user 'hive'. Make sure local file has permissions that allow 'hive' read access to it.